# 'dict' object has no attribute 'headers': it is coming from clickjacking.py

Tags: python, django

I have a method that generates pdf cheque for a client. the code as follows

```
@csrf_exempt
def generate_pdf(request):
    body = ujson.loads(request.body)
    monitoring = Monitoring.objects.filter(tr_id=body['tr_id']).first()
    if not monitoring:
        return {
            "message": MESSAGE['NotDataTrID']
        }


    data = {
        'headers': ["Abdulloh",],
        'user': monitoring.user,
        'tr_id': monitoring.tr_id,
        't_id': monitoring.t_id,
        'type': monitoring.type,
        'pay_type': monitoring.pay_type,
        'sender_token': monitoring.sender_token,
    }
    pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf_template.html', data)
    return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

it should generate a cheqeu in the end. But I am receiving an error from python env  it is coming from clickjacking.py. Can anyne help. I am using python 3.9 and centos 7 for operation system

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
if not monitoring:
        return {
            "message": MESSAGE['NotDataTrID']
        }
```

into

````
if not monitoring:
        return HttpResponse({
            "message": MESSAGE['NotDataTrID']
        })
    ```


You are getting this because you should return a proper response for django middleware
````